# What is the difference between SchedulePollingInterval, HeartbeatInterval, and ServerCheckInterval in hangfire configuration?

Tags: c#, hangfire

In Azure Application Insight > Application Map > Investigate performance, I am not sure why every 5 minutes, my service will have one or more database calls from hangfire. Not sure also why sometimes every 5 minutes, there will be only 1 db call but other times, there are 9 db calls.

These are some timestamps from the log data.

```
10/25/2022, 10:57:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:47:10 PM
```

I know it is from hangfire because when I comment out the hangfire code, I don't see my service call the database. I am not sure what is the difference between `SchedulePollingInterval`, `HeartbeatInterval`, and `ServerCheckInterval`. But I have set them all to `TimeSpan.FromHours(1)`. What I need is hangfire check if there is any job in the queue every hour. I can't find much information from hangfire documentation. https://api.hangfire.io/html/P_Hangfire_BackgroundJobServerOptions_HeartbeatInterval.htm

Here are my settings in program.cs. I am using .NET 6

```
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(
    options => {
        options.WorkerCount = 1;
        options.SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        options.HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        options.ServerCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    }
);

app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    StatsPollingInterval = 600000   
});
```

Some codes are removed for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure what is the difference between SchedulePollingInterval, HeartbeatInterval, and ServerCheckInterval.

- SchedulePollingInterval : the interval hangfire uses to check if there are some scheduled jobs to perform (does not seem relevant for your case)
- HeartbeatInterval : the interval each background job server uses to signal itself to the hangfire system
- ServerCheckInterval : I don't know for sure. I guess it is used to remove the old (timed-out) server instances

If you are using Sql Server as a storage, I think the setting which would be of much interest to you is `SqlServerStorageOptions.QueuePollInterval`. Setting it  to one hour should solve your problem.

Comment: I have set `QueuePollInterval` to one hour but no success.